# Can my backend call a smart contract function to be executed on a certain date?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

The architecture of my dapp consists of a backend (metamask + web3.js or web3.js + geth) and a smart contract that offers different services (functions). I want a function on the smart contract to run on a certain date. Can my backend call a smart contract function to be executed on a certain date? If it can, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a one-time command using 'at' command in unix to run a script file. The script file can be broadcasting a transaction calling the function on your smart contract.

If you plan to call the function every day or repeatedly, you can use 'cron' at unix.

https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/schedule-one-time-commands-unix-tool
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-job-scheduling/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Added to @ming question I would also say that it's important that your Smart Contract verify that it is the good moment to be called otherwise you inmutable logic will be a little weak and dependant only on the callers call.

Answer (score 0):

> Can my backend call a smart contract function to be executed on a certain date? If it can, how?

Usually these kind of calls cannot be guaranteed. It is better to create a function that anyone can call after a certain date. Even if your backend fails, others can pick up the work.